# The name pbwebdata does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

Now the error is The name pbwebdata does not exist in the current context. Do I need to declare the pbwebdata as public or something? If so, how would this be done?

```
namespace XXXX.Web2010
{
    [DefaultProperty("source")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:WebCustomControl1 runat=server></{0}:WebCustomControl1>")]
    public sealed class scriptLink : WebControl
    {
        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]

    public string source
    {
        get
        {
            String s = (String)ViewState["source"];
            return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["source"] = value;
        }
    }

    public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("");
    }
    public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write("");
    }

    protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
    {
        output.Write("<script src=\""+source+pbwebdata.GetCashBustingParameter(source)+"\"></script>");
    }

    public static string GetCashBustingParameter(string rootRelativePath)
    { 
        if (rootRelativePath.StartsWith(".."))
        {
            rootRelativePath = rootRelativePath.TrimStart('.');
        }
        string absolute = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(rootRelativePath);
        DateTime date = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(absolute);
        return "?rev=" + date.Ticks.ToString();
    }  
}
```

}

Do you have some Idea to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is saying it can't find where `pbwebdata` is in the method or class.

Your method uses it:

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    output.Write("<script src=\"" + source + pbwebdata.GetCashBustingParameter(source) +"\">/script>");
    //                                       ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Have you forgot to pass it into the class, and store it as a field variable?

---

To correct this compiler error, you could define a property on the class to pass it in, something like:

```
[DefaultProperty("source")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:WebCustomControl1 runat=server></{0}:WebCustomControl1>")]
public sealed class scriptLink : WebControl
{
    public pbwebdata pbwebdata
    {
       get; 
       set;
    }

    // As before
}
```

Then in your code you assign the `pbwebdata` from there:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
     // This will be in your partial class I assume?
     private scriptLink scriptLinkControl;

     protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         pbwebdata webdata = new pbwebdata();
         DoThingsWith(webdata);

         this.scriptLinkControl.pbwebdata = webdata;
     }
}
```

Comment: How can I pass it into the class and save as field variable?